# Hide/Delete a StaticText in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, hide

I was wondering how to hide/delete a StaticText in wxPython?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `control.Hide()` or `control.Show(False)`?

Comment: Thanks alot, did the trick! wxPython is a bit simpler than i thought :)

Answer (score 5):

The widget's Hide/Show methods should work. If the widget is in a sizer, then you can use the sizer's Detach method to "hide" it but not destroy it. Otherwise, the sizer has a Remove method that will remove the widget and destroy it. And there's the widget's own Destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

`statictext.Show` to show
and 
`statictext.Hide` to hide